# How to load data on azure search without create indexes on all the fields

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-search

I need to load some data(array of json object) into azure search, eachjson object contains 100 node, I dont want to create indexes on all the fields, I have created indexes on some of them but everytime I load data into azure search I'm getting this error :

> Uploading documents...

```
(node:44500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RestError: The request is invalid. 
 Details: parameters : The property 'status' does not exist on type 
 'search.documentFields'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by 
 the type.
```

my question is, Should I create the indexes on all the fields (100 fields)

Comment: Can you share the details about the request you're sending and the index definition?

Comment: Hi, it is a list of indexes, but the problem is when a field on the date does not indexed(not in the index definition) like this one status for example  it gives like this error

Comment: Thanks, but it remains unclear what you tried. If you're adding data to an index directly though [the add API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/AddUpdate-or-Delete-Documents), you can just omit fields that don't exist on an index. It's also unclear why you're creating more than one index.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create the indexes on all the fields.

What you are looking for is **output field mappings**. This way you can explicitly map the fields you want.

The documentation has an example that might be suited for your case -> [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-output-field-mapping?tabs=rest#flatten-complex-structures-into-a-string-collection)

Hopes this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the Example. I Hope it would help you somehow.**

```
var index = { 

name: "hotels", // name of the index

fields: [

    { name: "hotelId", type: "Edm.String", key: true, searchable: false },

    { name: "baseRate", type: "Edm.Double", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true },

    { name: "description", type: "Edm.String", filterable: false, sortable: false, facetable: false, searchable: true },

    { name: "description_fr", type: "Edm.String", filterable: false, sortable: false, facetable: false, searchable: true },

    { name: "hotelName", type: "Edm.String", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: true },

    { name: "category", type: "Edm.String", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: true },

    { name: "tags", type: "Collection(Edm.String)", filterable: true, sortable: false, facetable: true, searchable: true },

    { name: "parkingIncluded", type: "Edm.Boolean", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: false },

    { name: "smokingAllowed", type: "Edm.Boolean", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: false },

    { name: "lastRenovationDate", type: "Edm.DateTimeOffset", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: false },

    { name: "rating", type: "Edm.Double", filterable: true, sortable: true, facetable: true, searchable: false },

    { name: "location", type: "Edm.GeographyPoint", filterable: false, sortable: false, facetable: false, searchable: false }

]

};


var client = AzureSearch({

url : 'https://mysearch.search.windows.net',

key : 'mykey'

});


client.createIndex(index, function(err) {

if (err) throw err;

console.log('Index created');


client.addDocuments(index.name, [{

    hotelId : '1',

    baseRate : 199.0,

    description : 'Best hotel in town',

    description_fr : 'Meilleur hôtel en ville',

    hotelName : 'Fancy Stay',

    category : 'Luxury',

    tags : ['pool', 'view', 'wifi', 'concierge'],

    parkingIncluded : false,

    smokingAllowed : false,

    lastRenovationDate : '2022-06-27T00:00:00Z',

    rating : 5.0,

    location : '47.678581,-122.131577'

}], function(err) {

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Documents added');


    client.search(index.name, {search : '*'}, function(err, results) {

        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Found ' + results.length + ' results');


        client.deleteIndex(index.name, function(err) {

            if (err) throw err;

            console.log('Index deleted');

        });

    });

  });

});
```